# Error message AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'VERSION'

Tags: r, keras

I have just installed Keras in RStudio, and I followed the instructions in the webpage to use the mnist dataset, but it gives error message with no dataset loaded.

I have tried the following code:

```
library(keras)
install_keras()
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

And I also tried this code:

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
install_keras()
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

But I receive the following message:

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'VERSION'
```

Please, could you help me with this issue?

Comment: My guess is that you were not successful in installing all dependencies. See the documentation for your OS.

Comment: Hello @RomanLuštrik I am going to make a clean reinstall of MacOs Catalina, then install R, RStudio, Anaconda and then the libraries for keras. Hope it works, but as Jon mentions below, he has the same issue. Perhaps due to the new OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an earlier version of tensorflow worked for me on PC. In `R` I ran:

```
tensorflow::install_tensorflow(version = "1.13.1")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same error after my upgraded to macOS version 10.15 (Catalina). I'm using rstudio, and I tried a reinstall. I see no errors in the installation output below.

```
> devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
Skipping install of 'keras' from a github remote, the SHA1 (d357c68e) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
> devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras", force=TRUE)
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/keras@master
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/_9/wlywdjx556b9l20nwss4x0w40000gr/T/RtmpGk1Cpb/remotes163183656b0/rstudio-keras-d357c68/DESCRIPTION’
─  preparing ‘keras’: (3.6s)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (1.4s)
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory ‘keras/man-roxygen’
─  building ‘keras_2.2.5.0.tar.gz’

Installing package into ‘/Users/sporring/Library/R/3.5/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘keras’ ...
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (keras)
> library(keras)
> install_keras()
Using virtual environment '/Users/sporring/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate' ...
Collecting tensorflow==2.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/72/6b3264aa2889b7dde7663464b99587d95cd6a5f3b9b30181f14d78a63e64/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl
Collecting keras
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/fd/6bfe87920d7f4fd475acd28500a42482b6b84479832bdc0fe9e589a60ceb/Keras-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-hub
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/64/3bba86ca49ef21a4add11a4d37e3f6cd05d2e61d207ebe26a8a96b340826/tensorflow_hub-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting h5py
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/8b/4d01ae9a9d50a0bcc7b0b9aae41785d8d9de6fa9bba04dc20b1582181d2d/h5py-2.10.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d9/45/dd/65f0b38450c47cf7e5312883deb97d065e030c5cca0a365030/PyYAML-5.1.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/92/801710e21ede5f583c6bde61b25baa46ed16d9d77d74935e11b9a801cdd7/Pillow-6.2.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/06/1a696649f4b2e706c509cb9333fdc6331fbe71251cede945f9e1fa13ea34/scipy-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/5c/2e/7e/a1d4d4fcebe6c381f378ce7743a3ced3699feb89bcfbdadadd/gast-0.2.2-cp37-none-any.whl
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d7/de/2e/efa132238792efb6459a96e85916ef8597fcb3d2ae51590dfd/wrapt-1.11.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.6
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/33/376510eb8d6246f3c30545f416b2263eee461e40940c2a4413c711bdf62d/google_pasta-0.1.7-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/a7/15/a0/0a0561549ad11cdc1bc8fa1191a353efd30facf6bfb507aefc/absl_py-0.8.1-cp37-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/f4/acaa005b20777fc56a1dc0cae228ab2cb5a7f09a7e7fcb6d4619ce24a1b7/numpy-1.17.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.6.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/c6/a8b6a74ab1e165f0aaa673a46f5c895af8780976880c98934ae82060356d/protobuf-3.10.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_intel.whl
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/7c/06/54/bc84598ba1daf8f970247f550b175aaaee85f68b4b0c5ab2c6/termcolor-1.1.0-cp37-none-any.whl
Processing ./Library/Caches/pip/wheels/2c/b1/94/43d03e130b929aae7ba3f8d15cbd7bc0d1cb5bb38a5c721833/opt_einsum-3.1.0-cp37-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/a6/e8ffa4e2ddb216449d34cfcb825ebb38206bee5c4553d69e7bc8bc2c5d64/tensorboard-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.1.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/08/8b927337b7019c374719145d1dceba21a8bb909b93b1ad6f8fb7d22c1ca1/tensorflow_estimator-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/07/f1d41d10519ca165b0e078949078f20beb57e7e46dc0f1d56b73bb01270a/grpcio-1.24.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting astor>=0.6.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/4f/950dfae467b384fc96bc6469de25d832534f6b4441033c39f914efd13418/astor-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6a/8c1f62c37212d9fc441a7e26736df51ce6f0e38455816445471f10da4f0a/Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/da/55f51ea951e1b7c63a579c09dd7db825bb730ec1fe9c0180fc77bfb31448/urllib3-1.25.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/b0/8146a4f8dd402f60744fa380bc73ca47303cccf8b9190fd16a827281eac2/certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/9a/50fadfd53ec909e4399b67c74cc7f4e883488035cfcdb90b685758fa8b34/setuptools-41.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/42/3aeda98f96e85fd26180534d36570e4d18108d62ae36f87694b476b83d6f/Werkzeug-0.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/4e/fd492e91abdc2d2fcb70ef453064d980688762079397f779758e055f6575/Markdown-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: gast, wrapt, google-pasta, six, absl-py, numpy, setuptools, protobuf, termcolor, opt-einsum, h5py, keras-applications, werkzeug, grpcio, markdown, wheel, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, astor, keras-preprocessing, tensorflow, pyyaml, scipy, keras, tensorflow-hub, idna, chardet, urllib3, certifi, requests, Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-6.2.0 absl-py-0.8.1 astor-0.8.0 certifi-2019.9.11 chardet-3.0.4 gast-0.2.2 google-pasta-0.1.7 grpcio-1.24.1 h5py-2.10.0 idna-2.8 keras-2.3.1 keras-applications-1.0.8 keras-preprocessing-1.1.0 markdown-3.1.1 numpy-1.17.3 opt-einsum-3.1.0 protobuf-3.10.0 pyyaml-5.1.2 requests-2.22.0 scipy-1.3.1 setuptools-41.4.0 six-1.12.0 tensorboard-2.0.0 tensorflow-2.0.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.0.1 tensorflow-hub-0.6.0 termcolor-1.1.0 urllib3-1.25.6 werkzeug-0.16.0 wheel-0.33.6 wrapt-1.11.2

Installation complete.


Restarting R session...

> library(keras)
> mnist <- dataset_mnist()
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'VERSION'
```

Comment: Hello @Jon. I see that you have the same error as I do. By the way, this issue happened to me after installing the MacOs Catalina. I am going to make a clean reinstall again as you suggest.

Comment: I did an uninstall and reinstall of r and rstudio with no effect. I have not tried uninstalling anaconda 3

Comment: Could it be linked to Catalina's python installation? I tried to removing Anaconda and force Anaconda's Python but that gave other problems.

Comment: Hello @Jon after many attempts I decided to return to Mojave, and all was ok again, it seems that as it said in the message the attribute “version” was not available at the time.

Comment: @alexismenanieves Tensorflow is experiencing python 3.7.4 problems on Catalina, and I guess this is the real cause of our problems. For a while, I tried to make a virtual environment in conda with python 3.6, but as I said that gave other problems. Luckily, I've been able to postpone my need of Keras in R and Tensorflow on my laptop, so I will wait until Tensorflow hopefully soon is made to work again. Good luck.